# How to make a div and a link inline?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the `div` and `a` elementes below to appear inline:

The result should be like:

> Here is: [Link 1](http:///someurl)

But they didn't work. So appreciate your hints.

```css
.inline {
  float: right;
  display: block;
}
a.inline {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="inline">Here is:</div>
    <a href="/someurl" class="inline">Link 1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

P.S. I'm using **twitter bootstrap** as css framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `a.inline` styling and change your css to this:

```
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. I'm using twitter bootstrap. Maybe because of that?

Comment: @supermario  Well, for me it is? Could you share a working fiddle with your broken example? https://codepen.io/Aer0/pen/BQyKmg

Comment: Please refer to my updated question. I use twitter bootstrap. That may cause problem?

Answer (score 1):

`display: inline` will do the trick

```css
.inline{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<li>
<div class="inline">Here is: </div>
<a href="/someurl" class="inline">Link 1</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Sounds correct but does not work for me. Maybe because I use twitter bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

I think @aer0 answer is correct and If you adding

```
.inline{
  display: inline;
}
```

it should work. try to open your browser style console and see if it being override by some other css rule.

Answer (score -1):

Please add the link inside of the div element:

```
<div class="inline">
  Here is: <a href="/someurl" class="inline">Link 1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I can not do this because in reality `Here is` is separately generated from a template function.

Comment: Oh, in that case, please try

Comment: Oh, in that case, please try making the .inline element .inline{ display: inline;}